# Determine lowest level taxonomy term

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom 'location' taxonomy, with 3 levels: city -> region -> suburb.

When visiting an individual post, which has been tagged with a city, a region and a suburb, I want to also retrieve nearby posts. This means, other posts in the same suburb.

This gives me all the location terms assigned to the post:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $wp_query->post->ID, 'location' );
```

I found that if a term's parent equals 0, it is a city (top level).

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    if ( $term->parent == 0 ) {

        //$term is a city

    }
}
```

My question is: how can I determine which term is the suburb (lowest level)?

Comment: I had an idea: use the count attribute to compare all the terms. The one with less uses must be the suburb. But what if a region only has one suburb? both would have the same count

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is how the term ID's work between parent, child and grandchild. Take for example, you have a post that belongs to all three, in your question,

> city -> region -> suburb

`city` will have a lower numbered ID than `region` which in turn will have a lower numbered ID than `suburb`

With this in mind, order your terms by ID in reverse order, highest ID first. Look at [`wp_get_post_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms). You do the following

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_queried_object_id(), 'location', array( 'orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

You can then get the first entry in that array, which will be your grandchild term, or deepest level term, the term with the highest ID

Comment: Please see my update. Totally forgotabout the `order` parameter, and had a syntax error

Comment: This answer is wrong because it can't be guaranteed that the lower level terms in the hierarchy have higher IDs than their parents.

Comment: Wrong answer! As @rocknrollcanneverdie wrote.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by counting the ancestors of each term.

With the function get_ancestors() you can get an array containing the parents from lowest to highest in the hierarchy.

This worked for me:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_queried_object_id(), 'location', array( 'orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );

$deepestTerm = false;
$maxDepth = -1;

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $ancestors = get_ancestors( $term->term_id, 'location' );
    $termDepth = count($ancestors);

    if ($termDepth > $maxDepth) {
        $deepestTerm = $term;
        $maxDepth = $termDepth;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($deepestTerm);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem but it was more general. The situation was an unknown depth and multiple terms selected on the first level. Here is how i solved it:

```
function get_lowest_taxonomy_terms( $terms ) {
    // if terms is not array or its empty don't proceed
    if ( ! is_array( $terms ) || empty( $terms ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $filter = function($terms) use (&$filter) {

        $return_terms = array();
        $term_ids = array();

        foreach ($terms as $t){
            $term_ids[] = $t->term_id;
        }

        foreach ( $terms as $t ) {
            if( $t->parent == false || !in_array($t->parent,$term_ids) )  {
                //remove this term
            }
            else{
                $return_terms[] = $t;
            }
        }

        if( count($return_terms) ){
            return $filter($return_terms);  
        }
        else {
            return $terms;
        }

    };

    return $filter($terms);
}
```

The function returns the terms with the lowest level by using recursion. In each iteration it removes terms with no parents (level 1) and terms with parents that are not any more included in the set of filtered terms (levels > 1). Recursion ends by having an empty set and returning the result from the previous iteration.

My call would looked like this:

```
get_lowest_taxonomy_terms(get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'item_location'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my simple solution. Try this bro!

```
// Initialize variable
$result = array();
$getParentKeyInArray = array();

// Get the terms
$terms = get_the_terms($post_id, $taxonomy);

// Check if $terms is not empty
if($terms != null) :

    // Get all parent key in the array and add them inside another array
    foreach($terms as $term) :
        $getParentKeyInArray[] = $term->parent;
    endforeach;

    // Next, loop again and this time check if a category ID is not in 
    // $getParentKeyInArray if not then that's the lowest level taxonomy term
    foreach ($terms as $term) :
         if( !in_array($term->term_id, $getParentKeyInArray) ) :
             $result = $term;
         endif;
    endforeach;

endif;

// Check the result
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Have a nice day!